# Optimization of pointer access in OpenCL functions with parameters passed by reference(via pointers)

Tags: c++, c, pointers, opencl, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to optimize my OpenCL code currently a little bit. I use some pointers to return values. Is it more efficent to create temporary variables that are stored in registers (I guess at least) or can I directly access the pointers and use them throughout the function as it doesn't make any difference in performance, as the compiler optimizes this anyway?

Let me show you an example with a simple box ray intersection:

tmin and tmax are stored in temporary variables:

```c
bool intersect(const Ray* ray, float3 boxmin, float3 boxmax, float* tmin, float* tmax)
{
  float3 invR = 1.0f / ray->dir;

  float t1 = (boxmin.x - ray->origin.x) * invR.x;
  float t2 = (boxmax.x - ray->origin.x) * invR.x;
  float t3 = (boxmin.y - ray->origin.y) * invR.y;
  float t4 = (boxmax.y - ray->origin.y) * invR.y;
  float t5 = (boxmin.z - ray->origin.z) * invR.z;
  float t6 = (boxmax.z - ray->origin.z) * invR.z;

  float tmin_ = fmax(fmax(fmin(t1, t2), fmin(t3, t4)), fmin(t5, t6));
  float tmax_ = fmin(fmin(fmax(t1, t2), fmax(t3, t4)), fmax(t5, t6));

  if (tmax_ < 0)
    return false;
  if (tmin_ > tmax_)
    return false;

  *tmax = tmax_;
  *tmin = tmin_;
  return true;
}
```

direct access:

```c
bool intersect(const Ray* ray, float3 boxmin, float3 boxmax, float* tmin, float* tmax)
{
  float3 invR = 1.0f / ray->dir;

  float t1 = (boxmin.x - ray->origin.x) * invR.x;
  float t2 = (boxmax.x - ray->origin.x) * invR.x;
  float t3 = (boxmin.y - ray->origin.y) * invR.y;
  float t4 = (boxmax.y - ray->origin.y) * invR.y;
  float t5 = (boxmin.z - ray->origin.z) * invR.z;
  float t6 = (boxmax.z - ray->origin.z) * invR.z;

  *tmin = fmax(fmax(fmin(t1, t2), fmin(t3, t4)), fmin(t5, t6));
  *tmax = fmin(fmin(fmax(t1, t2), fmax(t3, t4)), fmax(t5, t6));

  if (*tmax < 0)
    return false;
  if (*tmin > *tmax)
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Well it's not the best example, because there are just three dereferenced pointers, where there might be no difference in performance, but it is just there to demonstrate what I mean.
Is there someone with deep enough knowledge, to know what most OpenCL compilers do in this case?
It would also be interesting to know what C/C++ compilers would do in such cases.

Comment: Which one is faster?  Yes.  One is faster.  Maybe.  Profile the two.  Benchmark each one.  Look at the machine code the two versions produce.  In short: test the two against each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the memory location of the pointer you pass (`tmax` and `tmin`).

- Private: The compiler will probably optimize them away.
- Local: Compiler can't optimize them away, unless it is clear for the compiler that the pointers are always pointed by a single work item in the group. (And even though it may still not do it). You may get some degradation in some cases with the case 2.
- Global: Compiler will never optimize them away, because it can't know if the global memory is being changed by another workgroup or even the CPU side. There will be a penalty, and extra memory accesses in the second case.

The best solution for performance is the first one. You do most of your checks in private space, and only access pointers to memory when needed. Don't worry about using extra variables, GPUs have enough registers for it:

```
  float tmin_ = fmax(fmax(fmin(t1, t2), fmin(t3, t4)), fmin(t5, t6));
  float tmax_ = fmin(fmin(fmax(t1, t2), fmax(t3, t4)), fmax(t5, t6));

  if (tmax_ < 0)
    return false;
  if (tmin_ > tmax_)
    return false;

  *tmax = tmax_;
  *tmin = tmin_;
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be any difference in performance between those two options with any decent compiler. Most OpenCL implementations are based on llvm and it will absolutely optimize away temps such as this.

That said, geneally the only easy way to tell is to time both options. This is always the proof of an optimization, but with CPU based compiler, one can often look at assembly output as well. That is more difficult to do with OpenCL.

Note use can use vector operations to make this code much more concise. Whether it helps performance or not is another story.

You can also return a struct I believe to avoid using pointers at all.

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I thought so, that the compiler is really smart. Optimizing towards the compiler would be wishable. maybe I will start some tests, to see if various theoretical optimizations will make a difference.
Well, I just copied the code from a project I made in C++, It's indeed true, that it is possible to optimize the code with vector operations. I will do that definitely.

Comment: Really the first thing you want to do is optimize for the explicit memory hierarchy. GPUs really require an empirical approach to performance optimization -- using profiling tools. CPUs do too but a lot of people seem to get away with ad hoc methods.